# 2D array inside a vector for multiple checkers boards

Tags: c++

I've got a 2D array which contains the current values of squares for a checkers game. The values change after every move. I want to save the state of the board after every move. So i decided to use a vector with a 2D array inside of it. (If this is possible)

```
std::array<std::array<int, 8>, 8> boardArr; //this is my board that keeps changing
std::vector<std::array<std::array<int, 8>, 8> > savedBoard; //thats where i want to save each board.
```

Can you tell me if this makes sense?
Also the functions where i tried to save each board and reset to the previous one:

```
void saveBoard()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++ )
      {
         savedBoard.at(moveCount).at(i).at(j) = boardArr.at(i).at(j);
      }
   }
}

void resetBoard()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
      {
         boardArr.at(i).at(j) = savedBoard.at( moveCount - 1 ).at(i).at(j);
      }
   }
}
```

What am i missing because when i try to call the save method while i have the opening state of the checkers game, it gives me this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

Comment: It is obvious from the error message, savedBoard is empty. Where do you fill it?

Comment: Consider encapsulating the 2 dimensional array representing the board into some class. Also don't use `.at` if you don't need bound checking. The idiomatic way to access indexed containers in C++ is through `operator[]`

Comment: Generally you don't want bounds checking on each access and indicates either that you have a logic error or that you lack user input validation layer.

Comment: @Sopel IMHO not a great advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To much unnecessary code. You access vector elements, but do not fill the vector.

```
void saveBoard()
{
   savedBoard.push_back(boardArr);
}
```